# Слайдер owl carousel 2 изменяет ширину слайдов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Слайдер работает отлично. Но временами почему-то задает ширину каждого слайда больше 1140, хотя я устанавливаю 566px, соответственно и высота меняется.

HTML

```
<div class="objects-carousel_two objects-carousel owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="./images/cert1.jpg">          
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="./images/cert2.jpg">          
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="./images/cert3.jpg">              
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="./images/cert4.jpg">              
        </div>          
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".objects-carousel_two").owlCarousel({ dots: false, nav: true, loop: true, navText: ['', ''], items: 1 });
```

CSS

```
.objects-carousel_two {
width: 566px !important;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Параметр autoWidth: true ?

Comment: Ставил в опциях autoWidth:false, но ситуация не меняется.

Comment: Дак true надо..

Comment: Это решило проблему с вытягиванием по длине. Теперь возникла новая проблема. Теперь временами показана половина одного слайда и половина следующего за ним...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, немного изменил код в js

JS

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
$(".objects-carousel_two").owlCarousel({ dots: false, nav: true, loop: true, 
navText: ['', ''], items: 1 });   
});
```